# How to make an autorole bot in python (discord.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, discord, discord.py

The code needs to be able to auto assign the role 'Noobies' and the role 'Level 0' to every new joiner. Ive been trying to adapt my code from using a command to making it assign a role as someone joins automatically however I think the message.server.roles is throwing it off and I don't know how to fix it. This is my first bot so please be gentle.

```
@bot.async_event  

async def on_member_join(Member : discord.User):  

    roles = [
        # IDs of the roles for the teams
        "333674108799942666",
        "351957337453363204",
    ]

    team_list = ["Noobies", "Level 0"]
    #entered_team = message.content[6:].lower()
    for team in team_list:

        role = discord.utils.get(message.server.roles, name=team)
        try:
            await client.add_roles(Member.name, role)
        except Exception as e:
                await bot.send_message(bot.get_channel("channel id"),'IT DIDNT WORK AHHH CONTACT SUPERDUPERDOOKEN OR EMI-SAN! and say: '+str(e))                
            #await client.send_message(message.channel, "Successfully added role {0}".format(role.name))
        #except discord.Forbidden:
            #await client.send_message(message.channel, "I don't have perms to add roles.")
```

Comment: look at the documentation for the parameters and their attributes

Answer (score 0):

`message` doesn't seemed to be defined in the function.

Perhaps you need to pass this into the function and avoid trying to rely on it as a `global`.